# How to identify the missing value

Tags: sql, vlookup, create-table

I have a table which each unique identifier contains more than one row of value, shown as below:

```
Row                 UniqueIdentifier                        ColumnA 
1                            UQ1                               Alpha   
2.                           UQ1                               Beta    
3.                           UQ1                               Charlie
4.                           UQ2                               Alpha
5.                           UQ2                               Charlie
```

The goal is to create an additional column/table to indicate the missing value (among alpha, beta, and charlie) like this:

```
Row UniqueIdentifier    MissValueIndicator
1      UQ1                     None
2.     UQ2                     Beta
```

There are unique identifiers which contain more than 3 values under column A however I am only looking to know if Alpha, Beta or Charlie missing (there are possibility one UQ miss two of those three also)

Thank you! Cathy

Comment: I assume the second row in your desired output is `UQ2`.  Also, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a complicated `case` statement and aggregation:

```
select UniqueIdentifier,
       coalesce(concat(max(case when ColumnA = 'alpha' then 'alpha;' end),
                       max(case when ColumnA = 'beta' then 'beta;' end),
                       max(case when ColumnA = 'charlie' then 'charlie;' end)
                      ), 'None') as WhatsMissing                  
from atable t
group by UniqueIdentifier;
```

This uses ANSI standard syntax.  Different databases may implement the `concat()` function in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a matrix of all `UniqueIdentifier` and `ColumnA` combinations.  Then you can filter for entries that are missing in your table:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  distinct UniqueIdentifier
        from    YourTable
        ) ids
cross join
        (
        select  'Alpha' as ColumnA
        union all
        select  'Beta'
        union all
        select  'Charlie'
        ) col_a
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt
        where   col_a.ColumnA = yt.ColumnA
                and ids.UniqueIdentifier = yt.UniqueIdentifier
        )
```